# Reducing memory requirements for convolutional neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create a convolutional neural network for images. I have currently about 136 images (many more will be added later) for 17 classes.

Each image is in the form of a `numpy.array` of shape `(330, 330, 3)`.

I am using the following code for net:

```
batch_size = 64
nb_classes = 17
nb_epoch = 2
img_rows = 330
img_cols = 330
nb_filters = 16
nb_conv = 3  # convolution kernel size
nb_pool = 2

model = Sequential()
# 1st conv layer: 
model.add(Convolution2D(
         nb_filters, (nb_conv, nb_conv),
         padding="valid",
         input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols, 3),
         data_format='channels_last',  )) 
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# 2nd conv layer: 
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, (nb_conv, nb_conv), data_format='channels_last')) 
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# maxpooling layer: 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(nb_pool, nb_pool), data_format="channels_last")) 
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# 2 FC layers: 
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta')

model.summary()

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=nb_epoch,  verbose=1  )
```

However, it gives a message that '>10% system memory is used' very soon after starting first epoch itself. It becomes unresponsive and I have to hard-reboot it.

What steps can I take or changes can I make in code to reduce memory requirements?

Comment: which training method your are using?

Comment: Your question is not clear. All methods are mentioned in the code above.

Answer (score 3):

By looking at the output of `model.summary()` you would find out what causes this problem (i.e. which layers have too much parameters):

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_189 (Conv2D)          (None, 328, 328, 16)      448       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_189 (Activation)  (None, 328, 328, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_190 (Conv2D)          (None, 326, 326, 16)      2320      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_190 (Activation)  (None, 326, 326, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_9 (MaxPooling2 (None, 163, 163, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 163, 163, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 425104)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 128)               54413440  
_________________________________________________________________
activation_191 (Activation)  (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 17)                2193      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_192 (Activation)  (None, 17)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 54,418,401
Trainable params: 54,418,401
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

​As you can see, since the output of `Flatten` layer is so big, the `Dense` layer would have too much parameters: `425104 * 128 + 128 = 54413440`, i.e. 54 million parameters for just one layer (and it is almost 99% of all the parameters in the model). So, how to reduce this number? You need to reduce the outputs size of convolution layers by using either `stride` argument (which I don't recommend) or pooling layers (preferably after each conv layer). Let's add two more pooling layers and one more conv layer (I even increased the number of filters in conv layers as we go deeper since it is usually a good thing to do):

```
# 1st conv + pooling layer: 
model.add(Convolution2D(
         nb_filters, (nb_conv, nb_conv),
         padding="valid",
         input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols, 3),
         data_format='channels_last',  )) 
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(nb_pool, nb_pool), data_format="channels_last"))

# 2nd conv + pooling layer: 
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters*2, (nb_conv, nb_conv), data_format='channels_last')) 
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(nb_pool, nb_pool), data_format="channels_last")) 

# 3rd conv + pooling layer:
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters*2, (nb_conv, nb_conv), data_format='channels_last')) 
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(nb_pool, nb_pool), data_format="channels_last")) 

# the rest is the same...
```

Model summary output:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_197 (Conv2D)          (None, 328, 328, 16)      448       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_203 (Activation)  (None, 328, 328, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_16 (MaxPooling (None, 164, 164, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_198 (Conv2D)          (None, 162, 162, 32)      4640      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_204 (Activation)  (None, 162, 162, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_17 (MaxPooling (None, 81, 81, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_199 (Conv2D)          (None, 79, 79, 32)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_205 (Activation)  (None, 79, 79, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_18 (MaxPooling (None, 39, 39, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_9 (Dropout)          (None, 39, 39, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_4 (Flatten)          (None, 48672)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 128)               6230144   
_________________________________________________________________
activation_206 (Activation)  (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_10 (Dropout)         (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 17)                2193      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_207 (Activation)  (None, 17)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 6,246,673
Trainable params: 6,246,673
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

As you can see, now it has less than 6.5 milion parameters, almost one-ninth of the number of parameters in the previous model. You can even add another pooling layer to reduce the number of parameters further. However, keep in mind that as your model becomes deeper (i.e. have more and more layers), you may need to take care of problems such as [vanishing gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem) and [overfitting](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/04/fundamentals-deep-learning-regularization-techniques/).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can really do, other than downscaling your input images, is to reduce your batch size until it works.

Also performing more pooling in your network (which isn't very deep) would help, as then the Dense layers would have way less parameters.

Answer (score 1):

"You need to go deeper" (c) =)

After 2 convolution/pooling layers you still have 80x80 image, which becomes a whopping 6400 large Dense layer after flattening. If you have only 17 classes, you need to go deeper, add more convolution and pooling, so your image becomes something about 20x20 (2 more extra conv/maxpool), then your network will work better and require less memory for Dense layers.

Comment: So, I should add 3-5 more sequences of `Convolution2D`+`Activation` layers. Should I also add `dropout` to each of these or let the dropout be only after maxpooling later?

Comment: my advice would be to search for vgg-16 and copy the first few layers from there. maybe the whole network. it's pretty small, designed for 224x224 images, but will gladly work with 330x330. you could train it in a few hours, however, I'd like to note, you don't have enough data for vgg16, something like several hundred thousands of images would be a good start. rule of thumb would be about 1000+ images for a single class. you have 17 classes, you do the math =)

Comment: Does it help if an image is rotated many times and fed into training set?

Comment: @mso image augmentation helps a bit, but this is usually the last resort. if you're able to get genuine training images, for for it.